# Calling a method on a object with a variable

Tags: php, methods

Can anyone explain why the following doesn't work :-

I get output with :-

```
var_dump($this->_payableItem->getNet());
```

But when trying to access it the following way I receive a error :-

```
$thresholdUnitMethod = 'getNet()';
$this->_payableItem->$thresholdUnitMethod
```

Error :-

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property:
>   PayableItem::$getNet() in

Comment: try using `call_user_func()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: You try: `$this->_payableItem->'getNet()'`

Comment: Bondye - that works! Why would PHP prevent you from including the () in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this:

```
$thresholdUnitMethod = 'getNet';
$this->_payableItem->$thresholdUnitMethod();
```

This will execute a function called `getNet` on `_payableItem`.

[More Info about Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) as such:

```
call_user_func(array($this->_payableItem, 'getNet'));
```